# Quicksort intermediate list printing Python

Tags: python, quicksort, in-place

The prompt for [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/quicksort3) HackerRank problem has me stumped. It is essentially a quicksort implemention but as an exception you are required to print the intermediate (or semi-sorted) "original" array in its entirety each iteration.

My working code without printing intermediates. It works as expected.

```
def quicksort(array):

    if len(array) > 1:
        left = 0
        right = len(array)-2
        pivot = len(array)-1
        while left <= right:
            while array[left] < array[pivot]:
                left +=1
            while array[right] > array[pivot]:
                right -= 1
            if left <= right:
                array[left], array[right] = array[right], array[left]
                left += 1
                right -=1
        array[left], array[pivot] = array[pivot], array[left]

        return quicksort(array[0:left]) + quicksort(array[left::])
    else:
        # return single element arrays
        return array
```

And below is my attempt at implementing a way to print intermediates. I.e. I am trying to keep the indices separate instead of just passing the spliced list like the above example so that I will always have access to the full array in the first function parameter.

```
def quicksort2(array, start=0, end=None):
    size = len(array[start:end])


    if size > 1:
        left = start
        right = len(array[start:end])-2
        pivot = len(array[start:end])-1
        print("Print")
        print("left: {}\nright: {}\npivot: {}".format(left, right, pivot))
        while left <= right:
            while array[left] < array[pivot]:
                left +=1
            while array[right] > array[pivot]:
                right -= 1
            if left <= right:
                array[left], array[right] = array[right], array[left]
                left += 1
                right -=1
        array[left], array[pivot] = array[pivot], array[left]
        print(array)
        print("the end is {}".format(end))

        size = len(array[0:left]) # 3

        return quicksort2(array, start=0, end=left) + quicksort2(array, start=left, end=left+(size-len(array)))
    else:
        # return single element arrays
        return array



if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = int(input()) # size is 7
    arr = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    print(quicksort2(arr, start=0, end=size))
```

However, now the list are not fully sorted on the second half of the input list so I am sure it has something to do with the end keyword parameter that is passed at the bottom of the quicksort2 definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. I really needed to use the [Lomuto Partitioning method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm) in order to satisfy the requirements of the print statements.

Code for anyone searching for this in the future

```
def partition(array, lo, hi):
    pivot_index = hi
    pivot_value = array[pivot_index]
    store_index = lo

    for i in range(lo, hi):
        if array[i] <= pivot_value:
            array[i], array[store_index] = array[store_index], array[i]
            store_index += 1
    array[pivot_index], array[store_index] = array[store_index], array[pivot_index]
    return store_index 


def quicksort(array, lo, hi):
    if lo < hi:
        p = partition(array, lo, hi)
        print(' '.join([str(i) for i in array]))
        quicksort(array, lo, p-1)
        quicksort(array, p+1, hi)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = int(input())
    ar = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    quicksort(ar, 0, size-1)
```